# Анимация в JavaFX

Tags: javafx

Задача:

1. Сделать окошко в JavaFX, накидать контента.
2. Сделать плавную анимацию при сворачивании и разворачивании окошка.
3. Сделать привязку к правой стороне экрана.

Проблема с пунктами 2 и 3.
Есть ли в JavaFX какое-то API для работы с анимацией?
И как можно сделать привязку окна к стороне экрана?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пакет `javafx.animation`

В общих чертах, в `Timeline` устанавливаются `KeyFrame`ы, в которых прописаны длительности и инструкции. При запуске `Timeline`, эти инструкции начинают выполняться потоком *GUI* `FXApplicationThred` с соблюдением заданных временных интервалов. Новых потоков не создается, но выглядит это как отдельный поток анимации.

Размер окна регулируется в `Scene`.

Расположение на экране и реакция на сворачивание - в `Window` (`scene.getWindow()`).

Данные о разрешении экрана - в `javafx.stage.Screen`.